# Word2010 Shapes GroupItems can't get TextFrame2.TextRange

Tags: vba, vsto, ms-office, ms-word, shapes

I open a docx,which is edit by word2010,in this doc,i have some shape which use group.but when I get the subshapes, i can't get the subshape Text.
this is my code.can someone tell me why? thanks.

```
Word.Application woradApp = new Word.Application();
            Word.Document doc = woradApp.Documents.Open(@"D:\ABC\a.docx");
            Word.Shapes Shapes =doc.Shapes;
            List<Word.Shape> list = Shapes.Cast<Word.Shape>().ToList<Word.Shape>();
            foreach (Word.Shape shape in list)
            {
                if (shape.Type == MsoShapeType.msoGroup)
                {
                    Word.GroupShapes dyShapes = shape.GroupItems;                  
                    foreach (dynamic item in dyShapes)
                    {
                        var range = item.TextFrame2.TextRange;
                    }
                }
            }
```

the "item.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text" code give a exception,as "TextRange" is null,this should be have text,where can get the text?

Answer (score 0):

Please show your what is `var range`, is it a `Range` object or `TextRange` object? I assume it's just a `variant array`.

Here are some steps to try out:

1. Make sure each shape supports [`TextFrame2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862416.aspx) property
2. `Ungroup` the `shapes` first
3. Loop through the shapes as you have done so to check the desired values
4. Make sure to handle `null` if `TextRange` has no value...which is the culprit most likely in your case.
5. Group the shapes.

   foreach (dynamic item in dyShapes)
   {
       if not IsNull(item.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text)
       {
          var range = item.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text;
       }
   }

First you can try out by handling `Null` in your current code. If that fails, then try the `ungrouping` suggestion.

Comment: Hi bonCodigo,Thanks for your answer.But I still cant get the text by your method.

Comment: Hi bonCodigo,
first use the "item.TextFrame2.TextRange" give a exception which is "TextRange {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 调用的目标发生了异常。 ---> System.ArgumentException: 指定的值超出了范围".I use the "quick watch",but can't find any Text info.
second using "shape.UnGroup()",get the ShapeRange,but still can't found any TextRange can use.
The doc is edit By Word2010 and saved as "Docx". if I use the above code for word2003,all is ok.
now I can't know what to do, can give me some suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Wendy369 please don't type Chinese here. This site operated in English. And you didn't mention your code is working in 2003 and fails in 2010 initially. Can we confirm your code is working for 2003?

Comment: ok，I will take care . My Code is working good for word2003.but I need it work well for Word2010.